# Detech event target from which position of Array

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

I have a loop MC which will be duplicate to stage several times according to every click.
Now I want to detect if the MC being click belongs to which position in the array.

```
private function levelsBG():void {

        LIST = new MovieClip();
        d++;

        for (var i:Number=0; i<myXML.children().length(); i++) {

            listMC=new MovieClip();


            LIST.addChild(listMC);

            listMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,listClick);
        }

        listArray.push(LIST);
        LISTmc.addChild(LIST);
        addChild(LISTmc);

        }

private function listClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
        var currentListArray=listArray[listArray.length-1];

        //trace from which position of Array
        trace(listArray.length-event.target.parent)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you lookup the parent? maybe use `mouseChildren = false`, so `event.target` points to you clip ...
to find the index, use `Array::indexOf`, so should be something like `trace(listArray.indexOf(event.target))` in the end ...

Comment: trace(listArray.indexOf(event.target)) return -1
so i use trace(listArray.indexOf(event.target.parent)) thanx! =D